# Скрыть/отобразить поле для ввода при выборе radiobutton

Tags: html, css, tilda

Всем привет!

Дорабатываю сайт на Tilda и очень ограничен в доработках с очки зрения кода. Мне нужно сделать следующий функционал: при выборе нужного RadioButton показывать скрытое поле.

Сам код radio кнопок:

```
<div class="t-input-block ">
  <div class="t-radio__wrapper">
    <label class="t-radio__control t-text t-text_xs" style="color: #333333">
      <input type="radio" name="poslanie" value="Текст 1" class="t-radio js-tilda-rule" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
      <div class="t-radio__indicator" style="border-color:#797979"></div>Текст 1
    </label>
    <label class="t-radio__control t-text t-text_xs" style="color: #333333">
      <input type="radio" name="poslanie" value="Текст 2" class="t-radio js-tilda-rule" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="2">
      <div class="t-radio__indicator" style="border-color:#797979"></div>Текст 2
    </label>
    <style>
      #rec658099306 .t-radio__indicator:after {
        background: #797979;
      }
    </style>
  </div>
  <div class="t-input-error" aria-live="polite" id="error_1702503462346"></div>
</div>
```

Код поля, которое нужно отобразить:

```
<div class="t-input-group t-input-group_in " data-input-lid="1702503574962">
  <label for="input_1702503574962" class="t-input-title t-descr t-descr_md" id="field-title_1702503574962" data-redactor-toolbar="no" field="li_title__1702503574962" style="color:#333333;font-weight:400; font-family: 'stolzl';">Текст</label>
  <div class="t-input-block ">
    <input type="text" name="Текст" id="input_1702503574962" class="t-input js-tilda-rule t-input_bbonly" value="" aria-describedby="error_1702503574962" style="color:#333333;border:1px solid #d9d9db;background-color:#f8fcff;">
    <div class="t-input-error" aria-live="polite" id="error_1702503574962"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Сразу скажу, что CSS я изучаю по ходу исправления сайта, но сейчас написал вот такую штуку

```
<style>
    .t-radio js-tilda-rule[value="Текст 2"]:checked ~ .t-input-group_in
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Но это не работает. Помогите разобраться, как правильно скр

Comment: Тильда как не крути - конструктор. Не понимаю пока что вы хотите сделать, что бы текст появлялся в рамках блока? Если так, то хватит стандартной Тильдовской анимации, поковырявшись сможете без кода это сделать, если показывать скрытый блок, то это уже совсем другое, и нужно анимировать именно появление блоков, используя ид этих блоков.

Comment: В Тильде вроде можно использовать js. Допиши свой вопрос и добавь этот тег